# Is it possible to use something other than a listview as sliding drawer in drawerlayout

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I would like to have for example a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout` sliding from the left of the screen instead of a lone `ListView`.

I tried to use à `LinearLayout` with `android:layout_gravity="start"` and i had this error at runtime:

```
ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot 
be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
```

here's the layout file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/ivwLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/video_icon"
        />

        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you referencing your DrawerLayout in code ? Can you maybe post that.

Comment: For others running into the `android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams` problem: **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939798/classcastexception-android-widget-framelayoutlayoutparams-to-android-support-v4)** directly answers that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have any view as the sliding part of a drawer layout. I prefer declaring a FrameLayout as the drawer and replacing it with my fragment, and it runs just fine.

The error you are getting is probably due to some other reason in the Java part of your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but, if I remove the linearlayout and the imageview to let the listview alone, I have no error and it work well. so I would be surprise that the error is in the java code.

Comment: Mind posting the code and logcat anyway? otherwise can't think of a reason what might be going wrong.

Comment: Finaly you were rigth, the error was in java. 
I had to change: 
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
for
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerView);
in the code where mDrawerView is the linearlyout instead of the list.
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: i am having an issue with this, i mean i have the framelayout and a fragment in it, but then i get an error saying that the framelayout is not a sliding drawer, is thre any thing i am missing? Please assist @SamarthJain

Comment: oh okie, i got it in the comments in the below answer, layout_gravity="start" is what i was missing!

Comment: @samarth I'm attempting to do what you described in your answer, I use a FrameLayout and use the fragmentmanager to load a listfragment into the drawer. However, I'm having trouble with scrolling in my listFragment being interrupted by the drawer. Can you help?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838120/vertical-scrolling-interrupted-by-oversensitive-drawerlayout-when-using-drawerla

Comment: @SamarthJain u can use replace  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList); this code with :mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(linearlayoutID); and it will load all u r layout into this.

Answer (score 63):

This will work if you move both the `android:id="@+id/left_drawer"` (or create a new id) and set the gravity.

The id move (or new one) is so the reference is correct so you call `closeDrawer()` on it and not the child views.

But most importantly, the `DrawerLayout` requires that element to have a `android:layout_gravity` set on it, as you mentioned.

Finally, you need to call close `closeDrawer()` on the base view, the one with the required gravity.

Example:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/ivwLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/video_icon" />

        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer_child"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In code:

```
DrawerLayout mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
LinearLayout mDrawerLinear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
ListView mDrawerListChild = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_child);

...

mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerLinear);
```

(This is basically what @Karakuri posted, but with a more complete explanation and example.)

Comment: having `android:layout_gravity` resolved my `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.LinearLayout@425d0d30 is not a drawer` error, in case anyone has the same error...

Comment: Same here, I changed the "mDrawer.closeDrawer" and moved the "android:layout_gravity="start"" to the linear layout.
Thanks :)

Comment: @OmarBizreh +1 for the correct comment, saved me alot of search!

Comment: Been tearing my hairs off, the gravity did the trick ! Thanks !

Comment: I was suffering so much my error was being mistaking `android:layout_gravity` for `android:gravity`  thanks!

Comment: Perfect! You got my heart!

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you pass correct object (your `LinearLayout` called mDrawerLinear) for methods like `isDrawerOpen, closeDrawer` etc. This line solved my `ClassCastException`:

```
boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerLinear);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try moving `android:id="@+id/left_drawer"` to the LinearLayout instead of the `ListView`