# Using Drawer layout and Scroll View in The Same Activity

Tags: android, scrollview, drawerlayout

I am trying to display a large block of text using TextView that cannot fit onto a screen. I have tried surrounding this view with a ScrollView and found when used in isolation it works. When I try to add a DrawerLayout, the scroll able action no longer works (but the DrawerLayout does). I am guessing that it's because of the DrawerLayouts requirement to use FrameLayout. Below is the xml code that I am using. Most of the code follows the google tutorial for drawerlayout at http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black" 
>    

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/city_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    />

   <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/city_title">    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/city_details"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
                    android:textColor="@color/white"/> 
        </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


   <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/content_frame"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are doing the drawer layout wrong. Re-read the documentations that you linked to, and have a look at this after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496007/edittext-inside-of-a-drawerlayout/17496206#answer-17496206

Comment: Why would you put the DrawerLayout **inside** a RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved my problem by creating a gesture listener that will listen for downward gestures. It solves the problem mostly with the exception that I now need to deal with jerky scrolling.