# Closing DrawerLayout causes exception : LinearLayout cannot be cast to DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to have a custom DrawerLayout that contains a ListView but I can't get it working. I was able to make it work before I wrap the content of a LinearLayout to be able to make it more custom and add an Image above the ListView.

I keep having this exception when i try to closeDrawer() while passing the linearLayout, I've seen multiple post about that kind of issue but the fix for most of them is to pass the LinearLayout to the closeDrawer() function, which I already did:

```
04-05 12:17:10.100 18879-18879/com.plante.android.cobalt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.plante.android.cobalt, PID: 18879
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.plante.android.cobalt/com.plante.android.cobalt.activityv2.ActivityHome}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerView(DrawerLayout.java:1415)
     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1630)
     at com.plante.android.cobalt.activityv2.ActivityHome.selectItem(ActivityHome.java:190)
     at com.plante.android.cobalt.activityv2.ActivityHome.onCreate(ActivityHome.java:155)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is my activity:

```
@Bind(R.id.drawer_layout)
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
@Bind(R.id.actionToolbar)
Toolbar toolbar;
@Bind(R.id.left_drawer_item)
LinearLayout mDrawerLinear;
@Bind(R.id.left_drawer_child)
ListView mDrawerListChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_v2_home);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mPlanTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.plan_list);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add("First Item");
    myList.add("Second Item");
    mDrawerListChild.setAdapter(new DrawerListAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_layout_item, myList));
    mDrawerListChild.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            toolbar,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            //syncActionBarArrowState();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            //mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        }
    };
    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(mOnBackStackChangedListener);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    user = getUser();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }

}


private void selectItem(int position) {
    BackHandledFragment fragment = new FragmentMobilePlan();
    setSelectedFragment(fragment);

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left, R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerListChild.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerLinear);
}
```

Here is my layout :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/action_bar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer_item"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profilIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_people1blue2x" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/left_drawer_child"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:background="#111" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ClassCastException android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939798/classcastexception-android-widget-framelayoutlayoutparams-to-android-support-v4)

Comment: WHere is your drawerlayout xml?

Comment: @Ben-J I added it, it didnt show because of the space in the post

Comment: @WilderPereira I already seen that post and it didnt help, I tried mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT); and also I wasnt passing the drawerLayout itself to the closeDrawer, so thats not my issue here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who stumble against the same issue, I was having this exception because the LinearLayout I passed to the DrawerLayout for closeDrawer() was not the second child of DrawerLayout in my XML. It had to be directly within the drawerLayout.