# Vertical Scrolling Interrupted by Oversensitive DrawerLayout When Using DrawerLayout with a ListFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview, drawerlayout

I'm attempting to use the DrawerLayout to display two fragments with the slideout fragment having a listview. I'm mostly following the example found on the [developers site](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

I have everything almost working, however when scrolling through the listview, any left or right movements in the scrolling motion will cause the scrolling to be interrupted and the drawerLayout to move horizontally.

Layout

```
             fragment A
-------------------------------------
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
|   Content Fragment    | Fragment A | 
|                       |            |
|                       | (ListView) |
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
|                       |            |
--------------------------------------
```

My Activity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <!-- The main content view -->
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 <!-- The navigation drawer -->
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_right"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

FragmentA.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/lightGray">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't have this problem if I use a normal ListView with the DrawerLayout, is there a way to stop the DrawerLayouts onTouch events from firing while my Listview is currently scrolling? I've tried setting setting my Fragment's rootview to be clickable = true, which didn't work.

Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the SwipeRefreshLayout was causing my scrolling issue. Removing the layout and using a separate 3rd party library fixed the issue for me.

Here's an open ticket on the SwipeRefreshLayout: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69074