# view android.widget.linearlayout is not a slidingdrawer

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, navigation-drawer

I need to implement such a layout : [image]

So to put the ImageView with the source right behind the listView when Navigation Drawer is opens.

My xml :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="320dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_list_layout"  android:gravity="start">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>

        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id ="@+id/drawer_logo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Implementation in the activity :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        drawer_list_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_list_layout);
....
```

But app crashes in the method selectItem :

```
 private void selectItem(int position) {
        // Update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new MapFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new RegisterFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new AboutProjectFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mScreenTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawer_list_layout); // - the line of crash. 
        } else {
            // Error
        }
    }
```

My onPrepareOptionsMenu

```
 @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawer_list_layout);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

So ,refers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939798/classcastexception-android-widget-framelayoutlayoutparams-to-android-support-v4), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738595/is-it-possible-to-use-something-other-than-a-listview-as-sliding-drawer-in-drawe) answers, which are similar to mine and implemented all the advices, I still get the trouble.

My stack :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.LinearLayout{428d39a8 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f05008d app:id/drawer_list_layout} is not a sliding drawer
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1170)
        at com.redonbas.MainActivity.selectItem(MainActivity.java:174)
        at com.redonbas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:97)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
```

Besides , I rebuilt the project - so it is not the case.

Experienced people just give a suggestion how can I implement such a feature in the app and what the reason of the crash.

Answer (score 3):

I once encountered the problem, and changing it from `android:gravity="start"`
to `android:layout_gravity="start"` solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, and I've implemented both

```
android:gravity="left"
```

and

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

Last, I changed the LayoutParams in code, It works:

```
DrawerLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.LEFT);
mDrawerLayout.updateViewLayout(linearLayout, layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.LinearLayout{428d39a8 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f05008d app:id/drawer_list_layout} is not a sliding drawer
```

Replace

```
boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawer_list_layout);
```

with

```
boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT);
```

**OR**

change LinearLayout's gravity to LEFT instead of START.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="320dp" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_list_layout"  
    android:gravity="left">
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: no, I've implemented both, but the problem remains.